# Print message alternately iin java

Tags: java, multithreading

Create a class named Application! Its main method (program entry point) should start two threads 0.5 seconds apart!

The result of the execution should be:

```
       first 0 54796(last 5 digits of the system in millisecond)
       second 0 55281
       first 1 55796
       second 1 56296
       first 2 56796
       second 2 57296
       ...
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat an action every 2 seconds in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296718/repeat-an-action-every-2-seconds-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will explain why you should share some code and what you have tired already. please describe exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: I tried to implement it, but no code works...

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with below approach, please don't take this code as final solution, you should try with your own approach.**

```
class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> printEveryHalfSecond("first"));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> printEveryHalfSecond("second"));

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
  }

  public void printEveryHalfSecond(String prefix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      String time = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
      System.out.println(prefix + " " + i + " " + time.substring(time.length() - 5));
      try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Please let me know if you need any further help.**